# Alternative for singleton when all activities need the same data

Tags: java, android

As I read, singletons are bad and one should avoid using them.

But I develop an App where most Activities and Fragments need to have access to the same dataset. The datas are stored in a an ArrayList and accessible through a singleton class.

What is bad about that? I can't create a new data-class object for each activity because the ArrayLists will be different. What is the alternative?

Comment: An ArrayList is not "storage". Use a database or something

Comment: use sharedprefrances

Comment: yes, but I need to cache the data. Otherwise I need to communicate with the server on every user interaction

Comment: singleton is not bad. just make sure its threadsafe

Comment: If you want to cache the data, there is nothing wrong in using a singleton class, as long as you are following good design principles.

Comment: Singletons are not "bad and one should avoid using them".

Comment: you can also use google gua chache where you can set cache to expire also

Answer (score 2):

> singletons are bad and one should avoid using them

In Android app development, we use singletons much more than in traditional Java development.

IMHO, the keys are:

- Use them *carefully*, making sure that you do not introduce memory leaks, race conditions, etc.
- Use them for *specific roles*, such as following the repository pattern, rather than just slapping `static` on everything because you want to make the compiler stop saying mean things to you
- Use them *reactively* (`LiveData`, RxJava, Kotlin coroutines, etc.), assuming that the data managed by the singleton is coming from something involving I/O (network, database, file, etc.)

> What is bad about that?

Possibly nothing. There may be issues with your specific implementation, but we have few details about that.

Comment: I have to access the same arraylist in all my activities and service. Sometimes i need to change the data in the arraylist, so i just call my setter again in my singleton which then overwrites the data and in my service i just call my getter to get that arraylist, what would be bad about this? Using a database doesn't seem right for my app because i'm just storing all songs that are on the device to play them. I also tried using putParcelableArrayListExtra but thats causing E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!! (parcel size = 1195060)

Comment: @VinceVD: "what would be bad about this?" -- it might not be necessary. "i'm just storing all songs that are on the device" -- you can get that information from `MediaStore`. You should not need to hold it in memory.

Comment: Yeah that's what i do, i have a song object where i have getters/setters which store information like song title, artist, genre etc.. that i get from MediaStore and then fill that arraylist with these song objects.

Comment: Then i can access this arraylist in my service and play a song with mediaplayer.setDataSource(songList.get(position).getData());

Comment: @VinceVD: Having a `SongRepository` supplied as a singleton by a dependency inversion framework (Dagger, Koin, etc.) is a solution if you feel that you really need the `ArrayList`. I would consider having my viewmodels work with `MediaStore` and get rid of the `ArrayList`, as I would like to avoid the need for a continuous out-of-date copy of the `MediaStore` data.

Comment: What do you mean with out-of-date copy of the MediaStore data?

Comment: i just loop through Mediastore columns for the information i need about a song each time i open the app and add them too the arraylist.

Comment: I'm just really confused about why a singleton is classified as anti pattern if it makes everything a lot easier.

Comment: @VinceVD: "What do you mean with out-of-date copy of the MediaStore data?" -- if the `MediaStore` content changes while your app is running, your app will not reflect those changes. "I'm just really confused about why a singleton is classified as anti pattern if it makes everything a lot easier. " -- that is covered in the answer.

Comment: Right, but for the MediaStore to change someone should for ex. upload a new song to the device while my app is running or are there other cases when the MediaStore changes overtime?

Comment: @VinceVD: The user might have some other app that syncs their local music catalog with ones from some sort of "music locker". The user might plug their device into USB and transfer over some music. Either of those things, and others, could happen when your app is running. Basically, you are making a copy of a database, and rarely is that a good answer if you have easy access to the original database, as you do here.

Answer (score 1):

Singletons aren't bad *per se*, the problem with them is when you start trying to test your code.

When you have a class/module/component/view that depends on one or more singletons, you have no way to control that dependency, so in a test environment you cant "mock" that singleton dependency or control whats data is in them (you can, but is really annoying having to clean all singletons before each tests, and even though that is error prone).

This can be easily solved using dependency injection. In Android the best framework for that is Dagger: https://google.github.io/dagger/
You can always use dependency injection by hand too, but having a framework that does the hard work for you is nice.

Then, with this approach, you kinda keep having singletons, but they are not really singletons in the way that they are in charge of only creating a single instance, but you (or the framework) are. Those classes are created only once (at the beginning or lazily) and then are injected in the components/clases that depends on them.
This way, you keep having all its features (sharing data between activities, fragments, etc), but, as you are injecting them, you can mock them an inject mocks for testing purposes.

Comment: Are you seriously suggesting to use dagger to someone who doesn't even understand how to use the same data in multiple activities

Comment: Where did I say that I don't understand how to use the same data in multiple activities? I'd asked for a better pattern. With singleton it works anyway.

Comment: He was asking for a better aproach to it. When you work in a big project that manages a lot of data that comes from a server, having a cache layer is a must. Many times, you have an cold cache layer (disk) and a hot short lived one (memory) To achieve that, you need singletons (o something that behaved like that). If his project doesn't use testing, singletons are just fine if you are careful. If you want something better, you need dependency injection, and to do that, there is nothing better than dagger due to Android's convoluted architecture.